# Chef script - read content of a file to use in http _request

Tags: ruby, httprequest, chef-infra

I have a chef script that want to read the value of a file.

```
http_request "create repo" do

  action :post

  url "http://chef.sparqlr.net:8080/openrdf-sesame/repositories/SYSTEM/statements?context=%3Curn:x-local:graph1%3E&baseURI=%3Curn:x-local:graph1%3E"

  headers "Content-Type" => "application/x-trig"

  message *<Read in content for a file>*

end
```

I would like the message of the post coming from a file, can anyone advise what the syntax should be?  I have try a few option, with ruby block etc but no luck.  Many thanks!

Comment: Is the file for the message already present on the node or is it deployed via chef too ? (answer may vary depending on this point)

Comment: The file already present on the node, thanks

Comment: `http_request` is a very complex wrapper of Net::HTTP and I'm not sure if you really want to use it. How about just using a `ruby_block` and standard ruby `Net::HTTP` ? Keep it simple and don't rely on too much magic.

Comment: @Roland I don't get your point there, Using directly `Net::HTTP` inside a `ruby_block` need more Ruby knowledge than using `http_request` resource with no benefit for doing so. I.e: if you add a notification in the resource, a `ruby_block` will trigger it irrespective of the success or not of `Net::HTTP` where `http_reques`t will trigger it only on success.

Comment: @Tensibai well, just check the source code. it's feature incomplete, e.g. doesn't support cookies. It's just usable for very limited requests. Available documentation about Net::HTTP is much better than about Chef::HTTP

Comment: @Roland indeed, the purpose is to do simple unitary requests, and according to the question, there's no need to go that complex. If you need a cookie in a chef Recipe you're doing something weird.

Comment: @Tensibai like downloading Oracle Software…

Comment: @Roland and thus breaking the license agreement of Oracle which did set the requirement to avoid direct downloads from their hosts. I hope you're warning your customers about this.

Comment: @Tensibai It's the way Chef, Inc. and Rackspace do it. Just check the source of the official java cookbook. https://github.com/agileorbit-cookbooks/java/blob/master/providers/ark.rb#L67-L87 - As you can see, they're even shelling out to curl.

Comment: @Roland this cookbook has no relation with Chef Inc. at all (Chef supported cookbooks are under https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks), it belongs to agileorbit. And the README state clearly [here](https://github.com/agileorbit-cookbooks/java#oracle) you have to override the default behavior to be aware it does things on your behalf or use a private repo to store the tarball. so yes, `http_request` is of no use here, but this is an edge case and has some legal consequences on some countries. We're stepping out of the question anyway, open a chat if you wish to discuss this more.

Comment: @Tensibai just do a "git blame"

Answer (score 1):

```
http_request "create repo" do
  action :post
  url "http://chef.sparqlr.net:8080/openrdf-sesame/repositories/SYSTEM/statements?context=%3Curn:x-local:graph1%3E&baseURI=%3Curn:x-local:graph1%3E"
  headers "Content-Type" => "application/x-trig"

  message ::File.read("/path/to/file")
end
```

You can use standard ruby classes to read a file, but as Chef has it's own File class you hav to prefix it with `::` to use the ruby class and not the Chef one.

In case the source file is deployed via chef you can wrap the File.read in a lazy block so it will be executed only when the provider is called.

Example:

```
template "/path/to/file" do
   source "file.erb"
end

http_request "create repo" do
  action :post
  url "http://chef.sparqlr.net:8080/openrdf-sesame/repositories/SYSTEM/statements?context=%3Curn:x-local:graph1%3E&baseURI=%3Curn:x-local:graph1%3E"
  headers "Content-Type" => "application/x-trig"

  message lazy { ::File.read("/path/to/file") }
end
```